# Uncheck 'SELECT ALL' when no checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

'SELECT ALL' working fine but the issue is when I uncheck all 'Item' then 'SELECT ALL' still display checked, this should unchecked if all 'Item' is unchecked.

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  $(".global-download-bar").toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.global-download-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">SELECT ALL
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item3

<div class="global-download-bar"></div>
```

Comment: First, you are using the same Id on every checkbox, thats not right. Second, try something like: http://jsfiddle.net/mvn945sy/20/

Comment: Please check it at: http://jsfiddle.net/mvn945sy/23/

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for `change` event of `checkItem` elements. If number of `:checked` checkboxes are same as of total element do the needful.

As Identifiers must be **unique** in HTML, use common class to target `checkItem` checkboxes.

```js
var childCheckboxes = $('.checkItem');

childCheckboxes.on('change', function() {
  var allChildCheckboxesChecked = childCheckboxes.length == childCheckboxes.filter(':checked').length;
  $('#checkAll').prop('checked', allChildCheckboxesChecked);

  //Maybe
  if (allChildCheckboxesChecked) {
    $(".global-download-bar").toggle();
  }
});

$("#checkAll").change(function() {
  childCheckboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
  $(".global-download-bar").toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.global-download-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">SELECT ALL
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item3

<div class="global-download-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a cleaner solution.

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('.checkItem, #checkAll').on('change', function() {
    if($('.checkItem').length == $('.checkItem:checked').length) {
      $("#checkAll").prop('checked', true);
      $(".global-download-bar").show();
    } else {
      $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
      $(".global-download-bar").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.global-download-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">SELECT ALL
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item3

<div class="global-download-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#checkAll').on('click', function() {
    if($('#checkAll').is(':checked')) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('input.checkItem').on('click', function() {
    let state = false;
    const checkboxes = $('.checkItem');
    state = Array.prototype.every.call(checkboxes, (ele) => {
        return $(ele).is(':checked');
    });

    if(state) {
        $("input#checkAll").prop('checked', state);
    } else {
        $("input#checkAll").prop('checked', state);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">SELECT ALL
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item3

<div class="global-download-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to add a handler to the `checkItem`s - if, on click, none are checked, uncheck the `checkAll` and hide the `global-download-bar`.

Do note that duplicate IDs in a single document is **invalid HTML** - best to use classes instead.

```js
const $checkAll = $("#checkAll");
$checkAll.click(function() {
  const { checked } = this;
  $('.checkItem').prop('checked', this.checked);
  if (checked) $(".global-download-bar").show();
  else $(".global-download-bar").hide();
});
$('.checkItem').click(function() {
  if ($('.checkItem:checked').length === 0) {
    $checkAll.prop('checked', false);
    $(".global-download-bar").hide();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.global-download-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">SELECT ALL
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">Item3

<div class="global-download-bar"></div>
```